# Count the bytes written to file via BufferedWriter

Tags: java, file, bufferedwriter

I am using BufferedWriter to write text with specific encoding to file, I want to count the file size in bytes before I close the file.

```
bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file),encoding),bsize);
bw.write(string);
```

My plan was to use string.getBytes() but this method doesn't allow to provide specific encoding (and I can't override the default encoding property).

Comment: `long fileSize = file.length();`

Comment: i can't, because file is not closed at this stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `String#getBytes(encoding)` instead

Comment: LOL, I am stupid was to lazy to scroll down the intellisense popup for other methods. Will accpet you answer in couple of minutes - there is a 10 min restriction...

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a method that works regardless of whether you're appending or not and does not duplicate data just for counting, store the reference to the `FileOutputStream` in a variable and access the `FileChannel` through `getFileChannel()`. You can call `long position()` before and after the data has been written, and the difference of the values will give you the number of bytes that have been written.

Comment: actually I don't need the "delta" but the size of written data up till a point, based on this I can decide if I should close a file and start a new one.

Comment: Then you don't need to record the value at the beginning, but just go with get the plain value returned by `position()`. Still requires no duplication of data just for counting of bytes, and eliminates the need to specify the encoding twice.

Comment: also, position() will work only after flush(), this is a problem because flush is done in latter stage.